# Why is $(h,k)$ in the vertex formula of a parabola $=a(x-h)^2 +k$ the vertex?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Why is it that in the form $y=a(x-h)^2+k$ of a parabola, that $(h,k)$ is the coordinate of the vertex? I am reviewing Algebra and cannot find a reasonable explanation anywhere.The highest level of math I am familiar is with Pre-Calculus. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the graph of the parabola $y=ax^2$. Its vertex is clearly at $(0,0)$. Now, if you replace $x$ with $x-h$ in any equation, its graph gets shifted to the right by a distance of $h$. Similarly, replacing $y$ by $y-k$ shifts the graph up by $k$. If we make both of these substitutions in the above equation of the parabola, its vertex gets shifted to $(h,k)$. The resulting equation after this substitution is $y-k=a(x-h)^2$, or $y=a(x-h)^2+k$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $(x-h)^2$ is always nonnegative, for any value of $x$, it's at its smallest when the thing in parens is zero, i.e., when $x = h$. If $a$ is positive, this will be where the parabola has its minimum, i.e., $x = h$ is the $x$-coord of the vertex. (If $a$ is negative, this is the location of the max, but the same result applies: $x = h$ is the $x$-coord of the vertex).

At $x = h$, the $y$-value is $a(h-h)^2 + k$< which is just $k$, so the vertex is at location $(h, k).

Comment: The only part I don't understand in this explanation is how can (x-h=0)? Wouldn't  [a(x-h)^2 -> a(0) -> a =0 ] occur and therefore no longer be a quadratic expression?

Comment: Let's make it explicit: suppose $a = 4$ and $h = 2$ and $k = 7$. Then the formula is $y = 4(x-2)^2 + 7$. Now in this formula, $x$ can take on any value, and for each $x$ we find a corresponding $y$, and the $(x,y)$ pairs so found form a graph. In finding $y$, there's always a $7$, but there's also an $(x-2)^2$ term. For different $x$-values, this term has different values. And when $x = 2$, it happens to produce the value $0$, which is the smallest possible. But in general, when you plug in any particular value of $x$, you end up with a *number*, not a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: I'm sorry I confused the property of a quadratic polynomial with parabolas! In ax^2 +bx +c = 0, a=/0 not in equations of parabola, back to studying!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the situation using transformations of functions.

We know the vertex of $y=x^2$ is located at $(0,0)$.

To translate the parabola horizontally $h$ units, we modify the input ($x$) value like $y=(x-h)^2$. Thus, the vertex is now at $(h,0)$.

The $a$-value is a vertical stretch or compression, and also determines whether the parabola is reflected over the $x$-axis. In any of these cases, the vertex of the graph of $y=a(x-h)^2$ doesn't move, so the vertex is still $(h,0)$.

Finally, we can vertically shift the graph $h$ units by adjusting the function values, like so, $y=a(x-h)^2+k$, resulting in a vertex located at $(h,k)$.